# How to get valid json output with mongosh version 1.10.5

Tags: json, mongodb, mongosh

How to get valid JSON output with Mongosh version 1.10.5?

Below is my mongosh query to get my desired results, I believe it is coming in BJSON(Binary JSON) format on which I'm unable to use jq tool for filtering the desired key: value pairs.

```
mongosh "mongodb+srv://testuser:xxxxxx@serverlesspentestdb.bu2mw.mongodb.net/testdb?retryWrites=true&w=majority" --quiet --eval 'db.testcheck.find({ "submittedAt": { $gt: ISODate("2023-10-06T00:00:00.000Z") }, "email": { $not: { $regex: /@(example\.com|example\.ai)$/i } } })'
```

So how do I modify it to get the desired JSON format output and not BJSON format?
I tried the below command using this https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongosh-json-output/116389/4 link but throwing `TypeError: EJSON.stringfy is not a function`

```
mongosh "mongodb+srv://testuser:xxxxxx@serverlesspentestdb.bu2mw.mongodb.net/testdb?retryWrites=true&w=majority" --quiet --eval 'EJSON.stringfy(db.testcheck.find({ "submittedAt": { $gt: ISODate("2023-10-06T00:00:00.000Z") }, "email": { $not: { $regex: /@(example\.com|example\.ai)$/i } } }))'



Error-Message
-------------
TypeError: EJSON.stringfy is not a function
```

How can I get the desired JSON format output and not BJSON format using mongosh for above query?

Comment: You're missing the second `i`, it's `stringify(...)` not `stringfy(...)`. FWIW I don't know that the format of that output will enable exactly what you want via `jq` processing but that is a separate question

Comment: Yeah, that's correct I missed that second ```i``` in that word. Thanks @user204442973